# How to optimize my writing from RAM to disc?

Tags: python, memory, optimization, fpga, ram

I have some python code for reading data from RAM of an FPGA and writing it to disk on my computer. The code's runtime is 2.56sec. I need to bring it down to 2sec.

```
mem = device.getNode("udaq.readout_mem").readBlock(16384)
device.dispatch()
ram.append(mem)
ram.reverse()
memory = ram.pop() 
for j in range(16384):
    if 0 < j < 4096:
        f.write('0x%05x\t0x%08x\n' %(j, memory[j]))
    if 8192 < j < 12288:
        f.write('0x%05x\t0x%08x\n' %(j, memory[j]))
```

Comment: Why are you doing append-reverse-pop? What type is `memory`? Does this dumping program, with apparent time restrictions, need to expand the data by 375% in the text conversion?

Comment: In my actual code I am not doing the append, reverse, pop in that order. I have some conditions(FiFo cross a pointer) for memory to be appended. I did not add that part for clarity.

Comment: Did you profile the code to confirm the section you did show us takes a considerable portion of the time?

Comment: I was using the timeit package to find the time for this section of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is very unefficient. You're literally iterating for nothing when values aren't in range. And you're spending a lot of time testing the indices.

Don't do one loop & 2 tests. Just create 2 loops without index tests (note that first index is skipped if we respect your tests:

```
for j in range(1,4096):
    f.write('0x%05x\t0x%08x\n' %(j, memory[j]))
for j in range(8193,12288):
    f.write('0x%05x\t0x%08x\n' %(j, memory[j]))
```

maybe more pythonic & more concise (& not using `memory[j]` so it has a chance to be faster):

```
import itertools
for start,end in ((1,4096),(8193,12288)):
    sl = itertools.islice(memory,start,end)
    for j,m in enumerate(sl,start):
        f.write('0x%05x\t0x%08x\n' %(j, m))
```

the outer loop saves the 2 loops (so if there are more offsets, just add them in the tuple list). The `islice` object creates a slice of the memory but no copies are made. It iterates without checking the indices each time for array out of bounds, so it *can* be faster. It has yet to be benched, but the writing to disk is probably taking a lot of time as well.

Comment: @eugenhu got another idea to get rid of the indices

Comment: I think the enumerate in the second code sample is missing a start argument. It'll make both output blocks start at 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Jean-François Fabre's observations on the loops are very good, but we can go further. The code is performing around 8000 write operations, of constant size, and with nearly the same content. We can prepare a buffer to do that in one operation.

```
# Prepare buffer with static portions
addresses = list(range(1,4096)) + list(range(8193,12288))
dataoffset = 2+5+1+2
linelength = dataoffset+8+1
buf = bytearray(b"".join(b'0x%05x\t0x%08x\n'%(j,0)
                        for j in addresses))

# Later on, fill in data
for line,address in enumerate(addresses):
    offset = linelength*line+dataoffset
    buf[offset:offset+8] = b"%08x"%memory[address]
f.write(buf)
```

This means far fewer system calls. It's likely we can go even further by e.g. reading the memory as a buffer and using `b2a_hex` or similar rather than a string formatting per word. It might also make sense to precalculate the offsets rather than using enumerate.